# Hive map reduce not working

Tags: hadoop, hive

When we are running aggregation query on hive table,it is failing with bellow exception.But `select * from table` is working fine.
we are using Apache `Hadoop 2.7.2`, `Hive 1.2.1`

```
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error caching map.xml: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /tmp/hive/dssbp/eb828a68-6637-41ea-a05e-d33ae658eb19/hive_2016-08-30_16-41-13_054_4952687673775889960-1/-mr-10004/a48247fe-12cd-4c9f-bf41-df67ffada26d/map.xml could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 2 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1547)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3031)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:724)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:492)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you select data, hive does not need to store intermediate results. It can simply produce the result directly.

If you were to do any kind of aggregation it needs to store its work somewhere.

The relevant part of the error here is:

> could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1). 
>   There are 2 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this
>   operation.

This means that hive cannot write its blocks to anywhere. Probably because the cluster is full (but possibly because it does not have the rights).

Comment: Thanks Dennis,physical memory was the issue,after cleanup it went through.